# Reading in ASCII characters from a file into an array

Tags: c, arrays

Hey guys so I'm stuck on how to read and scan in ASCII characters into an array from a file. The file will consist of ASCII data of varying length up to 512 bytes.

I know I need to dynamically allocate memory but not sure how large I should make it in order to read in the file and how to let it know that it reached EOF

An example of an input file is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
char* array = malloc(512 * sizeof(char); //but that doesnt seem right,
do{
    c = fgetc(enc) // enc is FILE Ptr
    array[i++] = c
    if(feof(enc))
       break;
while(1);
```

and then if I wanted to print back the array how would I move through the array without knowing the length? I can only think of using a for loop but how would I know what condition to make it run until?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For reading files always use **while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)**

Comment: Post declaration of `c`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this help. Basically, what I understand from your question is that you want to be able to read the file, store it in the array and be able to manipulate this array like printing values back.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

       FILE* enc = fopen("data","r");
       int number=0; 
       char data[80];int i=0;

       if (! enc ) // equivalent to saying if ( in_file == NULL ) 
         {  
            printf("oops, file can't be read\n"); 
            exit(-1); 
         }

      while ( fscanf(enc, "%c", & number ) == 1 )  
         { 

             data[i] = number;
               i++;
             //printf("We just read %c\n", data[i]); 

         } 

    int j=0;

    while(data[j]!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%c", data[j]);
      j++;
     }
   return (0);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering how you got char[80]?  We are told the maximum file size given would be 512 bytes(but it could be less), does that equate to a length of 80?  and would I figure out the size of the array if it is less than 512 bytes?

Comment: It's just a guess but not blind guess. 80 is a standard array size in such kind of array. Specifically, in this case, it has nothing to do with the memory size you gave in the question.

Comment: 1) `int number=0; ...  while ( fscanf(enc, "%c", & number )` wrong specifier for variable type.  2) No prevention for overrun of `data[]`.  3) `while(data[j]!=NULL)` may never be false before `j >= 80`.

Comment: @chux please run the code yourself. Above code does what it is supposed to do.